# nhibernate transactions and unit testing

Tags: sqlite, nhibernate, testing, transactions

I've got a piece of code that looks like this:

```
public void Foo(int userId)
{
    try {
        using (var tran = NHibernateSession.Current.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var user = _userRepository.Get(userId);
            user.Address = "some new fake user address";
            _userRepository.Save(user);
            Validate();
            tran.Commit();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception) {
        logger.Error("log error and don't throw")
    }
}

private void Validate()
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

And I'd like to unit test if validations ware made correctly. I use nunit and and SQLLite database for testing. Here is test code:

```
protected override void When()
{
    base.When();
    ownerOfFooMethod.Foo(1);
    Session.Flush();
    Session.Clear();
}

[Test]
public void FooTest()
{
    var fakeUser = userRepository.GetUserById(1);
    fakeUser.Address.ShouldNotEqual("some new fake user address");
}
```

My test fails.
While I'm debugging I can see that exception is thrown, Commit has not been called. But my user still has "some new fake user address" in Address property, although I was expecting that it will be rollbacked.
While I'm looking in nhibernate profiler I can see  begin transaction statement, but it is not followed neither by commit nor by rollback.
What is more, even if I put there try-catch block and do Rollback explicitly in catch, my test still fails.
I assume, that there is some problem in testing environment, but everything seems fine for me.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I've added important try-catch block (at the beginning I've simplified code too much).

Answer (score 3):

If the exception occurs before NH has flushed the change to the database, and if you then keep using that session without evicting/clearing the object and a flush occurs later for some reason, the change will still be persisted, since the object is still dirty according to NHibernate. When rolling back a transaction you should immediately close the session to avoid this kind of problem.

Another way to put it: A rollback will not rollback in-memory changes you've made to persistent entities.

Also, if the session is a regular session, that call to Save() isn't needed, since the instance is already tracked by NH.

Comment: Thanks for answer. What you write would be true, but in real code there is try-catch block in Foo(), I've forgot to write at the beginning. Sorry, my mistake! So I still have no clue where the problem is.

Comment: @Przecinek I've looked at your updated code. The try-catch in Foo() have the effect of swallowing the exception, which means that When() will continue as if nothing happened. Since the call to Foo() is followed by a call to session.Flush(), the change you made in Foo() will now be pushed to the database before your call to Clear(). This is the situation that my answer above describes.